# Telethon authorization Python

Tags: python, client, telegram, telethon

I have the following problem: I am trying to authorize a telegram client using a session created by telethon. When you run the code in the console, as befits, the phone number associated with the account is requested, followed by the confirmation code received from Telegram. And after entering the confirmation code, nothing happens, although a message about successful authorization should appear. After a few minutes of waiting for the program to work, a message about Incomplete login attempt arrives in the Telegram. Can you tell me what's the matter?

This is my code for making session:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = MY_API_ID
api_hash = "MY_API_HASH"
client = TelegramClient('first_session', api_id, api_hash)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=True, pattern=None))
async def greeting(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    await client.send_message(chat, "Hello, World!")

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

And results of launching the program in the terminal in the attached image
[Launching in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S59ps.png)

Comment: @СергейКох, The question was about the existence of any ways to deal with the problem of the program waiting for any actions after entering the authorization code received in the telegram. After entering the authorization code, a message about successful authorization should appear, but in my case this does not happen. That's the whole question

Answer (score 0):

The question is removed. For full authorization via telethon , you need to enter the method .start() pass the password="12345" parameter, where 12345 is the two-factor authentication password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).